# Removing specific menu items?

Tags: functions, menus

I used the following to remove certain menus for the "editor"

```
function remove_menus () {
        global $menu;

        if( (current_user_can('install_themes')) ) { 
            $restricted = array(); } // check if admin and hide nothing
            else { // for all other users

                // Remove Tools, Appearance, Links, Plugins, Comments,
                if ($current_user->user_level < 10)
                $restricted = array(__('Posts'),  __('Links'), __('Appearance'), __('Tools'), __('Settings'), __('Comments'), __('Plugins')); // this removes a lot! Just delete the ones you want to keep showing
                end ($menu);
                while (prev($menu)){
                    $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
                    if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
                }
            }
        }

    add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

This works except now the client has asked to remove the following:

On the dashboard, remove the "Add New Page".

[image]

Under the "pages" tab, remove the "Add New Page":

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you not just change permissions on the user?

Comment: ?? Does changing the permissions remove specific items from the menus?

Comment: What permission level would remove "Add Pages"? Writer?

Comment: Not roles, permissions. As in disallow `edit_pages` or something. Just hiding them on the menu like you're doing (as far as I'm aware at least) is merely security by obscurity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much simpler solution is to use `remove_menu_page` ,  `remove_submenu_page` and `remove_menu` (admin bar).

Your example of removing the sub-menu item for "add new" would be

```
remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page', 'post-new.php?post_type=page' );
```

To remove it from the admin menu bar you can use the example in @BandonRandon's post.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that there's no need to mess around with menu globals anymore. Since WP 3.1 (or thereabouts) we have 2 new functions to play with, which let you remove any page from the menu:

```
remove_submenu_page( $menu_slug, $submenu_slug );
remove_menu_page( $menu_slug );
```

An example usage would be this:

```
remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'post-new.php' );
```

To restrict access to a page without the use of a plugin (depending on the situation it might be overkill) you can use the $pagenow global:

```
function my_restrict_access() {
    global $pagenow;

    if( $pagenow == 'post-new.php' && ! current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) )
          wp_redirect( admin_url() );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_restrict_access', 0 );
```

Comment: Your example also applies to posts (I think) , to specify pages you can add `?post_type=page`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with m0r7if3r you'll want to use a role editing plugin to make it so the user can't add/edit pages. Once that is done you can do something like this to hide the menu.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'wpse_47731_remove_admin_menus',11 );
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpse_47731_remove_admin_bar_links' );
add_action('admin_head','wpse_47731_hide_admin_buttons');

function wpse_47731_remove_admin_menus() {
    if (!current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
        //pages
        global $menu;
        global $submenu;
        unset( $menu[75] );
        unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'][10][1]);
    }
     else {
        return;
    }
}

function wpse_47731__hide_admin_buttons(){
  global $current_screen;
  if (!current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ))     {
        if ( ($current_screen->id == 'edit-page' ) || ( $current_screen->id == 'page'))
            {
               echo '<style>.add-new-h2,#add_gform{display:none;}</style>';  
        }
        else if( ($current_screen->id == 'edit-post' ) || ( $current_screen->id == 'post'))
           {
            echo '<style>#add_gform {display:none;}</style>';  

        }
    else{
        return;
    }

}
}

function wpse_47731_remove_admin_bar_links() {
    if (!current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
        global $wp_admin_bar;
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-page');
    }
}
```

That's basicly the code I use I'm assuming you may already be hooking into these with your function but you'll have to play with it a bit. When I originally did it I found a super good article on Google explaining how it all worked but I have lost the bookmark but if I  find it I'll make sure to post.

Here is Justin Tadlocks post (which is pretty good) http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/13/removing-menu-pages-from-the-wordpress-admin